# Error 9 activating a workbook in a different path

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to select data in a workbook that is in a specific path I get error 9.

Here my code:

```
   myPath = "Z:\7. Personnel\Florian\Projet_BDC\Test\"
   myPath2 = "Z:\7. Personnel\Florian\Projet_BDC\Test\Consolidations\"
   Set sht = Workbooks("Consolidation.xlsm").Worksheets(2)

Set wbconso_dest = Workbooks.Add
    wbconso_dest.SaveAs Filename:=myPath2 & "Consolidation." & Dateconso & ".xlsx"
    Workbooks(myPath & "Consolidation.xlsm").Activate
    sht.Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=wbconso_dest.Worksheets(1)
    wbconso.Close
```

At this line I get the error:

```
 Workbooks(myPath & "Consolidation.xlsm").Activate
```

Comment: Is the workbook actually open at this point? If so, just use the workbook's name you don't need to supply the full path. If it isn't open then you need to open it before you can activate it

Comment: It's active. i supressed the path, but i have another error : 1004

Comment: The methode select of range classe failed

Comment: I really dont know why i can't select this A1 cell in the second page of the workbook consolidation...
i did this many times but i can't see why i can't now .

Comment: The real question is *why do you need to?* There is no need to use `.Select` for anything in VBA

Comment: I need to select data to be able to copy ?

Comment: I want to copy a dynamic table (that's why i used xltoright and down.

Comment: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy` no you don't :)

Comment: Thank you. i still dont understand why select doest work in this case but Ok !